# Getting a value from the class in a JAR file

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

I want to run a method in JAR, and the method will look like `public static SomeType getValue()`.

I tried to use reflection and it seemed okay:

```
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{jarFile.toURI().toURL()}, Main.class.getClassLoader());
Class targetClass = classLoader.loadClass("some.package.TargetClass");
Class targetType = classLoader.loadClass("some.package.SomeType");
Method getValueMethod = targetClass.getMethod("getValue");
```

But while getting a return value like this:

```
targetType value = targetClass.cast(getValueMethod.invoke(null));
```

`value`'s type cannot be `targetType`, isn't it? However, the type `SomeType` is in the JAR file, so I can't do like `SomeType value = ~~`

Then, how can I get `getValue()`'s value properly and access its data?

Comment: Using reflection, too. But why are you doing that? Why isn't the jar file in your classpath? What are you trying to achieve, at a higher level?

Comment: Because `jarFile` can be dynamically changed. But setting a classpath is a static way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use interface to restrict the return value.

If the return value has no limit, you operate on it means you know all about it. So what's the meaning of your 'dynamic loaded'?

Abstract a normal interface `SomeInterface`, and then

```
SomeInterface value = targetClass.cast(getValueMethod.invoke(null));
```

Other code only work for `SomeInterface` but don't need to know what actual it is. It's the interface's power be.